# D3js: Can I change the number of ticks to a variable number of days?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to change the number of days between ticks based on dynamic data (csv). All of the examples I have found seem to use a fixed set of dates.

```js
var outerWidth = 600;
var height = 200;
var margin = {
  top: 40,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 40
};
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %d, '%y");
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, outerWidth], 0.1); // 0.05
var scaleticks = 5;
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickPadding(8)
  .ticks(scaleticks)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d"));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10);
var svg = d3.select("#cases").append("svg")
  .attr("width", outerWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data = [{
    "date": "2020-08-01",
    "deaths": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-02",
    "deaths": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-03",
    "deaths": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-04",
    "deaths": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-05",
    "deaths": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-06",
    "deaths": "1"
  }
]
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.deaths;
});
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-0.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-0.55em") //.55
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="rtecenter" id="cases">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can, but please add a [mre]. That will make your question easier to answer.

Comment: If possible, I'd appreciate sample code.

Comment: If this is your chart, please take the code, strip away all the non-essential parts, and upload it here. Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I am sorry. I posted this question to Reddit and they suggested I post it here. I can't post any examples of code I have tried because I can't find any code to try. I am a bit of a hacker since usually I look for examples but all of the examples I have found so far have a fixed set of dates which I don't have.

Comment: I understand that, most people approach d3 using examples, no problem. Can you give us the code you have right now - without the variable dates?

Comment: I posted it here https://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/9v1bmjL6/1/